Получить месяцы, которые начинаются с понедельника
Необходимо получит в виде запроса все месяцы, которые начинаются с понедельника в таблице
CREATE TABLE CalendarDate (
TheDate date not null
,TheDay smallint Not null
,TheWeek smallint
,TheWeekName char(15)
,TheMonth smallint
,TheMonhName char(10)
,TheQuarter smallint
,TheYear smallint
)

РЕЗУЛЛЬТАТ:


Мне кажется, что что-то не так с данными. TheWeekName - название дня? Попробуйте SELECT TheMonthName FROM CalendarDate WHERE TheWeekName = "Monday" AND TheDay = 1

Спасибо.
SELECT TheDate, TheWeekName
FROM CalendarDate
WHERE TheWeekName = 'Monday' AND TheDay = 1
ORDER BY TheDate
